# Google Map VS GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, geolocation

I'm developing an Android Application, and i need to get the current location of the user. I'm wondering what is the best way to do so: using GPS or Google Maps.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think Google Maps use?

Surprise! It also uses GPS.

So getting it manually will be faster than loading a map and checking the location.

Note: you can also get your location through a network which will usually be faster (but probably less accurate).

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps uses GPS **and** Mobile Data, so it is probably more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Play Location Services](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html), it adds an abstraction layer to all the location stuff, so you dont need to care about what is android doing to get the location.